# @media (prefers-color-scheme: light) not working in chrome

Tags: css, themes

I'm using:

```
@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
  :root {
    --shade1: hsl(var(--HS-color), 0%);
    --shade3: hsl(var(--HS-color), 70%);
    --shade2: hsl(var(--HS-color), 90%);
    --lighten: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 10%);
    --background-lighten: hsla(var(--HS-color), 80%, 80%);
  }
}
```

To switch to a light theme if the system preference is light but dark is the default on my website. For some reason, these root styles are applying in chrome even though my system theme is dark and I've tried relaunching chrome too. Even more strangely it works in the chrome-based edge. Any answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**
it turns out for some reason since I was using Force Dark Mode for Web Contents flag in chrome://flags chrome was making the colour scheme light even though it's supposed to make it dark.